# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Trying to select a Menulink i tried through various options like through Linktext, Xpath but it shows cannot find such element.
The HTML expression is:

```
<div class="bd">
  <ul class="first-of-type"> 
    <li class="yuimenubaritem clsmenubaritem yuimenubarItem-has submenu first-of-type" id="MenubarItem_new1428659607679" groupindex="0" index="0"> <a href="javascript :void(0);" class="yuimenubaritemlabel yuimenubaritemlabel-hassubmenu">New</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tired all my possible options which are

1)

```
    WebElement menulink = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//* [@id='MenuBarItem_new1428659607679']"));
    Actions action= new Actions(wd);
    action.moveToElement(menulink).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000L);
```

2)

```
    WebElement menulink=wd.findElement(By.linkText("New"));`
```

3)

```
    WebElement menulink=wd.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'first of type')]and //li[contains(@id,'MenuBarItem_new1428643471800') ] "));
    menulink.findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();
    menulink.click();
```

Comment: Can you post html code for menu link please?

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.bd li.submenu a")).click();
```